# How to convert pptx file full slides to images using Python 3.11?

Tags: python-3.x, python-pptx

I am getting   File "<COMObject >", line 2, in Open
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147024894), None) while I am using win32com.client package.

I should be able to convert to each individual slide to a image .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please remove the python-pptx tag - as this is nothing to do with that package.